# python invoking PV-Wave

Tags: python, linux

'/usr/local/bin/wave' only accepts a filename as input, so I need to invoke the process, then "send in" the commands, and wait for the output file to be written. Then my process can proceed to read the output file. Here is my code that does not write to the output file:

```
hdfFile = "/archive/HDF/16023343.hdf"
pngFile = "/xrfc_calib/xrfc.130.png"
lpFile = os.environ['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] + pngFile
waveCmd = "hdfview, '" + hdfFile + "', outfile='" + lpFile + "', web, view='RASTER', /neg"
os.environ['WAVE_PATH'] = "/oudvmt/wave/pro:/dvmt/wave/pro"
wfile = subprocess.Popen ('/usr/local/bin/wave >&2', shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
wfile.stdin = "\@hdf_startup\n\@hdf_common\n" + waveCmd + "\nquit\n"
```

Comment: I found an answer to my question: The last 2 lines are as follows:wfile = subprocess.Popen ('/usr/local/bin/wave >&2', shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
wfile.stdin = "\@hdf_startup\n\@hdf_common\n" + waveCmd + "\nquit\n"

Answer (score 0):

I found what I was missing. The change is to the last 2 lines. They are:

```
wfile = subprocess.Popen ('/usr/local/bin/wave', stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
wfile.communicate("\@hdf_startup\n\@hdf_common\n" + waveCmd + "\nquit\n")
```

I needed to set "stdout" to avoid extra output from PV-Wave.
I needed to use "communicate" to wait for the process to complete.